# How do we achieve sort by two different fields in Spark-Core?

Tags: apache-spark

I am doing some basic programming in spark

**InputFile  :**

```
2008,20
2008,40
2000,10
2000,30
2001,9
```

**My Spark-Code :**

```
scala> val dataRDD = sc.textFile("/user/cloudera/inputfiles/year.txt")
scala> val mapRDD = dataRDD.map(elem => elem.split(","))
scala> val keyValueRDD = mapRDD.map( elem => (elem(0),elem(1)))
scala> val sortRDD = keyValueRDD.sortByKey(true,1)
res29: Array[(String, String)] = Array((2000,30), (2000,10), (2001,9), (2008,20), (2008,40))
```

I want output to be sorted by year in ascending order and for each year the values to be sorted in descending order

**Expected output:**

```
2000,30
2000,10
2001,9
2008,40
2008,20
```

Can someone help me on getting this result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to define class which holds year and value for year. This class should extend Ordered by overriding compare method. Than you use the objects of this class as a key values and apply sortBy operation.

```
class TwoKeys(var first: Int, var second: Int) extends Ordered[TwoKeys] {
    def compare(that: TwoKeys): Int = {
      if(first == that.first){
        that.second - second 
      }else{
        first - that.first
      }
    }
  }
...
val keyValueRDD = mapRDD.map(elem => (TwoKeys(elem(0), elem(1)), TwoKeys(elem(0), elem(1))))
val sortRDD = keyValueRDD.sortByKey(true,1)
```

Comment: yes,It works, But I would to  like to understand some explanation on compare method? What does that.second - second ? Are we subtracting? Please explain logic that you have written inside compare method

Comment: compare returns -1, 0 or 1, which correspond to less, equal and bigger respectively.